# not receiving extras from custom notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a custom notification which has two buttons, when I click the button it opens `CustomNotificationListener` and I pass some extras which I am able to receive in the `CustomNotificationListener`.
But if the user clicks on the notification and not on the buttons it will take the user to `MainActivity` and I am passing extras `fcmService` to the intent but when I look for extras in MainActivity it is always null.

```
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
```

I have also tried `flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` still do not get extras in MainActivity.

Could you suggest what can be the problem please.

This is the code for custom notification.

```
    private fun showCustomPushNotification(message: RemoteMessage, chargerId: String, pushMessageType: PushMessageType) {
            val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(
                packageName,
                R.layout.plugin_requires_approval_notification_small
            )
            val notificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(
                packageName,
                R.layout.plugin_requires_approval_notification_large
            )

            val title = message.data[MSG_TITLE]
            val subTitle = message.data[MSG_SUB_TITLE]

            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title)
            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubTitle, subTitle)

            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title)
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubTitle, subTitle)

//            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
//                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
//            }
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        }
            intent.putExtra("fcmService", "customNotification")

            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            val customNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this,
                CarInfoProcessingService.APPROVE_EACH_PLUGIN_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
            )
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .build()

            val approveIntent = Intent(this, CustomNotificationListener::class.java)
            approveIntent.putExtra("pushMessageType", "$pushMessageType")
            approveIntent.putExtra("onClickListener", "approve")
            approveIntent.putExtra("chargerId", chargerId)
            val pendingApproveIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                0,
                approveIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnApprove, pendingApproveIntent)

            val denyIntent = Intent(this, CustomNotificationListener::class.java)
            denyIntent.putExtra("pushMessageType", "$pushMessageType")
            denyIntent.putExtra("onClickListener", "deny")
            denyIntent.putExtra("chargerId", chargerId)
            val pendingDenyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                1,
                denyIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )

            notificationLayoutExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDeny, pendingDenyIntent)

            val notificationManager =
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.notify(CustomNotificationListener.WHAT_NOTIFICATION_ID, customNotification)
    }
```

MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val fcmServiceExtra = intent.getStringExtra("fcmService")
    Log.d("fcmExtra", "$fcmServiceExtra")
```

Please suggest
thanks a lot in advance
R

Answer (score 0):

Setting some unique dummy action to intent might help :

```
        val notificationId = getNotificationId()
        intent.action = "dummy_action $notificationId"

        private fun getNotificationId(): Int {
          return (1000 until 9000).random()
        }
```

And for the flags i'm using like below:

```
        intent.addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        )
```